# Ggplot facet wrap, leaving only upper and side labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having issues creating a plot with facets. It has 57 plots so I to be very considerate with space. I would  like to leave names of stations on the top and years on the sides. Is there a way to set labels only for specific facets?

Here is an example plot:

```
ggplot(x)+ 
  geom_col(aes(x = days, y = irish_rules),size= 1)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 40) ) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())+
  facet_wrap(~id, ncol = 3)+
  theme(strip.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

And here is sample of the data:

```
x <-structure(list(id = c("1983_Birr", "1983_Birr", "1983_Birr", 
"1983_Birr", "1983_Birr", "1983_Birr", "1983_Birr", "1983_Birr", 
"1983_Birr", "1983_Birr", "1983_Birr", "1983_Birr", "1983_Birr", 
"1983_Birr", "1983_Birr", "1983_Casement", "1983_Casement", "1983_Casement", 
"1983_Casement", "1983_Casement", "1983_Casement", "1983_Casement", 
"1983_Casement", "1983_Casement", "1983_Casement", "1983_Casement", 
"1983_Casement", "1983_Casement", "1983_Casement", "1983_Casement", 
"1983_Kilkenny", "1983_Kilkenny", "1983_Kilkenny", "1983_Kilkenny", 
"1983_Kilkenny", "1983_Kilkenny", "1983_Kilkenny", "1983_Kilkenny", 
"1983_Kilkenny", "1983_Kilkenny", "1983_Kilkenny", "1983_Kilkenny", 
"1983_Kilkenny", "1983_Kilkenny", "1983_Kilkenny", "1984_Birr", 
"1984_Birr", "1984_Birr", "1984_Birr", "1984_Birr", "1984_Birr", 
"1984_Birr", "1984_Birr", "1984_Birr", "1984_Birr", "1984_Birr", 
"1984_Birr", "1984_Birr", "1984_Birr", "1984_Birr", "1984_Casement", 
"1984_Casement", "1984_Casement", "1984_Casement", "1984_Casement", 
"1984_Casement", "1984_Casement", "1984_Casement", "1984_Casement", 
"1984_Casement", "1984_Casement", "1984_Casement", "1984_Casement", 
"1984_Casement", "1984_Casement", "1984_Kilkenny", "1984_Kilkenny", 
"1984_Kilkenny", "1984_Kilkenny", "1984_Kilkenny", "1984_Kilkenny", 
"1984_Kilkenny", "1984_Kilkenny", "1984_Kilkenny", "1984_Kilkenny", 
"1984_Kilkenny", "1984_Kilkenny", "1984_Kilkenny", "1984_Kilkenny", 
"1984_Kilkenny"), short_date = structure(c(4953, 4954, 4955, 
4956, 4957, 4958, 4959, 4960, 4961, 4962, 4963, 4964, 4965, 4966, 
4967, 4953, 4954, 4955, 4956, 4957, 4958, 4959, 4960, 4961, 4962, 
4963, 4964, 4965, 4966, 4967, 4953, 4954, 4955, 4956, 4957, 4958, 
4959, 4960, 4961, 4962, 4963, 4964, 4965, 4966, 4967, 5320, 5321, 
5322, 5323, 5324, 5325, 5326, 5327, 5328, 5329, 5330, 5331, 5332, 
5333, 5334, 5320, 5321, 5322, 5323, 5324, 5325, 5326, 5327, 5328, 
5329, 5330, 5331, 5332, 5333, 5334, 5320, 5321, 5322, 5323, 5324, 
5325, 5326, 5327, 5328, 5329, 5330, 5331, 5332, 5333, 5334), class = "Date"), 
    irish_rules = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    3, 16, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 9, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    days = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
    13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
    12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
    11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
    9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L)), .Names = c("id", 
"short_date", "irish_rules", "days"), row.names = c(NA, -90L), vars = "id", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0:14, 15:29, 30:44, 45:59, 60:74, 75:89), group_sizes = c(15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L), biggest_group_size = 15L, labels = structure(list(
    id = c("1983_Birr", "1983_Casement", "1983_Kilkenny", "1984_Birr", 
    "1984_Casement", "1984_Kilkenny")), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = "data.frame", vars = "id", drop = TRUE, .Names = "id"), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I edited your post to include the (gg)plot. I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. Do you want to remove facets? Could you please explain based on the plot?

Comment: You need to separate out your `id` string column, into year and text. Then you can use `facet_grid(text ~ year)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `separate` the `id` column into `year` and `station` then use `facet` on them

```r
library(tidyverse)

x1 <- x %>% 
  as.tibble() %>% 
  separate(id, c("year", "station"))
x1

#> # A tibble: 90 x 5
#>    year  station short_date irish_rules  days
#>    <chr> <chr>   <date>           <dbl> <int>
#>  1 1983  Birr    1983-07-25          0.     1
#>  2 1983  Birr    1983-07-26          0.     2
#>  3 1983  Birr    1983-07-27          0.     3
#>  4 1983  Birr    1983-07-28          0.     4
#>  5 1983  Birr    1983-07-29          0.     5
#>  6 1983  Birr    1983-07-30          0.     6
#>  7 1983  Birr    1983-07-31          0.     7
#>  8 1983  Birr    1983-08-01          0.     8
#>  9 1983  Birr    1983-08-02          0.     9
#> 10 1983  Birr    1983-08-03          0.    10
#> # ... with 80 more rows

ggplot(x1) + 
  geom_col(aes(x = days, y = irish_rules),size= 1)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 40) ) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())+
  facet_grid(year ~ station)+
  theme(strip.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

Created on 2018-03-15 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).